# C# if statement skipped even if condition is met

Tags: c#, if-statement

im writing a basic program on c# for school and im having trouble with an if statement where the condition gets met but the code gets skipped as if the condition wasn't met.

```
//this runs when i select a cell on the dataGridView
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{    

    string estado = "";
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        id_lbl.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        nombre_lbl.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        apellido_lbl.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        estado = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    }

    id_lbl.Visible = true;
    nombre_lbl.Visible = true;
    apellido_lbl.Visible = true;

    if(estado == "Activo")
    {
        baja_btn.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (estado == "NoActivo")
    {
        alta_btn.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(estado);
    }
}
```

code runs but if statement jumps directly to else code and message box displays Activo, how ever, `baja_btn.Enabled = true;` does not run.
same is true if i select row with NoActivo. if jumps straight to else...

Note: the ACTUAL value of estado just before entering the if statement is Activo. so as it is it SHOULD go into the first condition but it skips all the way to else..

Comment: i forgot to mention that i also tried the `if(estado.Equals("Activo"))` but got the same result..jumped straight to else code.

Comment: Are you sure, that strings are really equal? Have you checked for any spaces at the start and end of your `estado` `string`? Also, have you verified, that casing is same as well?

Comment: You have to provide the estado string result from row.Cells[7].Value.ToString().

Comment: maybe there is a spacing in your cell value Put a break point at the line of code: id_lbl.Visible = true; Check the value of estado

Comment: Try this: `String.Equals(estado.Trim(), "Activo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` it will remove spaces and compare ignoring cases

Comment: the value of `string estado` is Activo, i've checked casing and spaces.. i would post an image of the message box but i need 10 points reputation..

Comment: debug is your friend, you probably have a space at the end of the `row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()` or the `row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()` is actually `activo` or `e.RowIndex` isn't greater than `0`. Again debugging is your friend

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i just tried your line but it gets the same result, skipps stright to else and shows messagebox with Activo written in it..

Comment: @JoelContreras how do you valdiate that `estado` is `Activo`?

Comment: @JoelContreras: could you, please, put a breaking point on `if (estado == "Activo")` and copy actual value of `estado` to the question?

Comment: well. besides actually checking for loose spaces or wrong letter casing(wich i did before even posting) i use as debug the messagebox that displays the string content of estado wich is Activo writen just like in the condition..

Comment: i just placed the break point just before entering the if statement and the value of estado is Activo.. so it should go right into the `if(estado == "Activo")` but it jumps to else and show a messagebox with Activo written in it..

Comment: How do you fill the datagrid? It might very well be that there are some characters that look the same, but aren't (Unicode is a lot of fun).

Comment: i filled the dataGridView from sql database on form load with `this.usuariosTableAdapter.Fill(this.inventariosDataSet7.Usuarios);`

Comment: Try this Joel. Just before the if, put this line `estado="Activo"`. If that works, then estado is not "Activo"...

Comment: @Pikoh thank you, this worked.. but if i use `MessageBox.Show(estado);` instead of `estado = "Activo";`  the message box displays Activo.. what could be happening here?

Comment: Joel `Activo` is not the same as `Activo   `,as the second one has spaces. Try to change this line to be like this: `estado = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString().Trim();` As a general rule, I always do `ToString().Trim()` when assigning values from a database to avoid this kind of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `string`s are not equal. To see where and why, let's try debug report (just before `if`):

```
  ... 

  String report = String.Format(
    "Tested [{0}] encoded {1} of length {2}\r\nActual [{3}] encoded {4} of length {5}",
    estado,
    String.Join(" ", estado.Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4"))),
    estado.Length, 
    "Activo", // <- copy/paste all "Activo" from the if
    String.Join(" ", "Activo".Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4"))),
    "Activo".Length);

  MessageBox.Show(report);

  if(estado == "Activo") // <- if of the question
    ...
```

Please, have a look at the report: where do you have differences? I've got two equal strings

> Tested [Activo] encoded 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f of length 6
>
> Actual [Activo] encoded 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f of length 6

but in your case there should be differences

**EDIT:** the experiment has shown that the tested value is

> Tested [Activo ] 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f 0020 0020 0020 0020 of lenght 10

So you have *trailing spaces*, it´s typical for many RDBMS: you have, say, `CHAR(10)` field in the table, and so you're given **10** character string. To solve the problem you can just trim the trailing spaces:

```
 if (estado.TrimEnd() == "Activo") 
 {
    baja_btn.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: thank you.. aparently i have two spaces after Activo on estado, but this are not on sql registry.. simething is odd but alteast now i know exactly my problem and where to start looking for a solution.. thank you very much..

* Tested [Activo  ] 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f 0020 0020 0020 0020 of lenght 10

* Actual [Activo] 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f lenght of 6

Comment: @JoelContreras: spaces can be diffrent (' ', non breaking space, thin space etc.). Since my `String.Equals(estado.Trim(), "Activo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` *doesn't* help, you have not just two ordinal spaces but something else. What is the *encoded* tested value?

Comment: Tested [Activo ] 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f 0020 0020 0020 0020 of lenght 10  Actual [Activo] 0041 0063 0074 0069 0076 006f lenght of 6

Comment: @JoelContreras: you do have spaces (*four* of them). So `if (String.Equals(estado.Trim(), "Activo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { baja_btn.Enabled = true;}` should work

Comment: Thank you very much.. apparently the first time i checked your line i was missing an extra set of () somewere or something.. a straight copy and paste `if (String.Equals(estado.Trim(), "Activo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { baja_btn.Enabled = true;}` worked like a charm.. marking this as answer.. and again, thank you very much..

Comment: @JoelContreras: you're welcome! I suspect RDBMS returns the value with trailing spaces.